How can I query the (DC1's) catalog from peered (DC2) ? DNS works using modified query but I can't get it done via REST or using consul binary
I have two clusters (DC1 - the one with IP .11.33, and DC2 - with IP .11.44):
The first one has a few services, one which (graylog) is exported so that peered DC2 can see it.
Peering:
root@consulclient:~# CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=192.168.11.33:8500 ./consul peering list
Name  State   Imported Svcs  Exported Svcs  Meta
dc1   ACTIVE  0              0
dc2   ACTIVE  0              1

root@consulclient:~# CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=192.168.11.44:8500 ./consul peering list
Name  State   Imported Svcs  Exported Svcs  Meta
dc1   ACTIVE  1              0
dc2   ACTIVE  0              0

--
Query using DNS:
(asking dc1, where the service is "held" and exported from):

dig graylog.service.domain.com @192.168.11.33 -p 8600

;; ANSWER SECTION:
graylog.service.domain.com. 0 IN      A       192.168.11.7

(asking dc2 for dc1's service):

dig graylog.service.dc1.peer.domain.com @192.168.11.44 -p 8600

;; ANSWER SECTION:
graylog.service.dc1.peer.domain.com. 0 IN A   192.168.11.7

--
Catalog:
root@consulclient:~# CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=192.168.11.33:8500 ./consul catalog services
consul
dummy
graylog
kubernetes

root@consulclient:~# CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=192.168.11.44:8500 ./consul catalog services
consul

I would expect a way to see the services that are "imported" into dc2 from dc1.
I don't see any option to do that, using REST or consul binary. Any ideas how can I achieve that ?
_edit, the only resemblance of what I need that I found was using the /health endpoint described here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/connect/config-entries/exported-services
curl --request GET http://192.168.11.44:8500/v1/health/service/graylog?peer=dc1

Thanks
